# Conflict between Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have already created mssql db and project (class library) for data access layer at .net framework. Then I created project at asp.net core.
To access to this db I use in startup class within `ConfigureServices` method. I use EF core in asp.net core project.

```
services.AddDbContext<TradeEvoDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDb")));
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TradeEvoDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And here is my DbContext class which reference to my class library proj.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TradeEvo.Chat.Identity;
using TradeEvo.DAL.Models;

namespace TradeEvo.Chat.Models
{
    public class TradeEvoDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<GlobalSettings> GlobalSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserApiSettings> ApiSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEBaySettings> EBaySettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User1CSettings> User1CSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserPayPalSettings> PayPalSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyInfo> CompanyInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PromInfo> PromInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductInfoMultiLang> ProductInfoMultiLang { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PosterImage> PosterImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderNote> OrderNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItemMont> OrderItemsMont { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItemMontKey> OrderItemsMontKey { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItemMontLink> OrderItemsMontLink { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItemMontFile> OrderItemsMontFile { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogComment> BlogComments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TradeEvo.DAL.Models.Chat> Chats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StatusType> StatusType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StatusTypeMapping> StatusTypeMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DistributorProduct> DistributorProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductType> ProductType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductContent> ProductContent { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductInfo> ProductInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductMontChanges> ProductMontChanges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductGenreMapping> ProductGenreMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAttributeValue> ProductAttributeValues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAttributeMapping> ProductAttributeMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAttributeCombination> ProductAttributeCombinations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAttributeCombinationMapping> ProductAttributeCombinationMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCharacteristic> ProductCharacteristics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCharacteristicValue> ProductCharacteristicValues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductListAttribute> ProductListAttributes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductPromAttribut> ProductPromAttributes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductList> ProductLists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductListMapping> ProductListMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAvailability> ProductAvailability { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserLanguage> UserLanguages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResourceMultiLang> ResourceMultiLang { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PromUaCategories> PromUaCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderPromInfo> OrderPromInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItemProm> OrderItemProm { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bank> Bank { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipientAddress> RecipientAddress { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SenderAddress> SenderAddress { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderInvoice> OrderInvoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CityNP> CityNP { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StreetNP> StreetNP { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WarehouseNP> WarehouseNP { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderManufacturer> OrderManufacturs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purse> Purses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentSystem> PaymentSystem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MoneyMovement> MoneyMovement { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MoneyMovementData> MoneyMovementData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MoneyMovementType> MoneyMovementType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductMultiDownloadData> ProductMultiDownloadData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShippingService> ShippingServices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShippingServiceUserMapping> ShippingServiceUserMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShippingServiceCountryMapping> ShippingServiceCountryMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShippingServiceProductMapping> ShippingServiceProductMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPAddress> UPAddress { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPaddresses> UPaddresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPEmails> UPEmails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPPhones> UPPhones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPClient> UPClient { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NPClient> NPClient { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PAdresses> PAdresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipientAddressCustomService> RecipientAddressCustomService { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPShipment> UPShipment { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPParcels> UPParcels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPParcelItems> UPParcelItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPDiscount> UPDiscount { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPDiscountPerClient> UPDiscountPerClient { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPInternationalData> UPInternationalData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UPLifeCycle> UPLifeCycle { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ImportExportSettings> ImportExportSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ImportExportStructure> ImportExportStructures { get; set; }
        public TradeEvoDbContext(DbContextOptions<TradeEvoDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when i try to access my users table such as:

```
var user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == args[1]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or:

```
var user = await _userManager.Users.FindByIdAsync(args[1]);
```

I got next exception:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. File can not be found.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

All stacktrace is:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Не удается найти указанный файл.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()
   at System.Attribute.GetIndexParameterTypes(PropertyInfo element)
   at System.Attribute.InternalGetCustomAttributes(PropertyInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.NotMappedMemberAttributeConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__0(Object k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at TradeEvo.Chat.Controllers.HomeController.<ChatAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in myproj
```

And my controller looks like:

```
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly TradeEvoDbContext _context;
        public HomeController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<HomeController> logger,
            TradeEvoDbContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }
```

If I use nuget manager and install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, I will fix only this error and got new also at this line of code. `System.Web.HttpPostedFile ... File can not be found`

What am I doing wrong? Or how to connect to existing db ? I'm stuck.

**Edit #1**
Asp.net Core project, csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.0.1" />
```

**Edit #2**
What's wrong?
[image]

Comment: Don't mix ASP.NET Identity with EF Core. Either use ASP.NET Core Identity with EF Core or ASP.NET with EF6

Comment: @Tseng, so will i need to recreate my class library to .net core and use EF core within?

Comment: No, you can use ASP.NET Core and EF Core with .NET Framework too. You only need .NET Core (the runtime) / .NET Standard if you want to target Linux or get some of the performance benefits of .NET Core. If you have legacy dependencies which require .NET Framework, stay on it until you can migrate away from it

Comment: @qwiz no, you should *remove* `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. That's the wrong package. It's a 3-year old package for non-Core ASP.NET and EF

Comment: @qwiz why did you add extra packages anyway? ASP.NET Core project templates already include the appropriate packages. Were you trying to solve another problem and thought a package was missing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in which project or class? Maybe you or me didn't understand. I didn't use this package in asp.net core project. I use this in  my class library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  "why did you add extra packages anyway?" - because error said that: File can not be found.

Comment: @qwiz no, the error didn't say that. You didn't post the *original* error that made you add the unrelated `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package. In any case, any ASP.NET Core project except the empty ones contains the package references for Core Identity and EF Core. If you remove `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` you can use a project as if it were a library too - the csprojs files won't differ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, can you read my question again? I got next exception:

{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. File can not be found.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169583/discussion-between-qwiz-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @qwiz can you read the comments again? You are referencing an [unrelated package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/). The correct one is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/). I found that by checking the `csproj` file of an existing ASP.NET Core project and the `project.assets.json` file in `obj`. Why did you add that other package?

Comment: @Tseng, i understand that i shouldn't mix this technologies. but how I can fix my problem? What should i do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, my csproj, look at edit in question

Comment: @qwiz wrong packages!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, where? I'm confused now

Comment: @qwiz read the comments **again**. I already explained this. Core packages have Core in the name. Besides `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` means all. You didn't have to add the other packages

Comment: @qwiz go to the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All) package page and check the dependencies. You'll see it *already* contains Owin, IdentityCore, EFCore etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, delete all wrong packages. but error is still here. check edit #2 in question

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your project references what is the version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' library and cross verify it with the version in web.config file for the same library. Change the version in web.config file to the correct version of the library referenced in the project. This will resolve your issue.

You can also check the version in packages.config file,

[image: packages.config]

And update the version in web.config as below,

[image: web.config]

Comment: You are forcing a *downgrade* and the screenshots aren't even about .NET Core. There's no `package.config` in .NET Core

Comment: There is a class library project created where the issue with the library is  occurring, it is not in the .net core project. And as the class library project does not have the entity framework library, I am assuming it must be added through nuget manager. This will automatically add the packages.config in the class library project.

Comment: There's no package.config, web.config or app.config in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Library references implicitly include libraries referenced by that library. Put more simply, if you have library X that references EF 6 and you include it library Y that references EF Core. Library Y will then have references to *both* EF 6 and EF core.

You can mix and match your usage of EF6/EF Core, but you must segregate them from each other. If you need some portion of the library that references EF 6, you'll have to break that out into it's own separate library with no references to EF 6.

Comment: But how i can include my DAL project into my asp.net core project? Am i need to create new DAL project to access my db in .net core? Or what?